# Uncaught Error: [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(plugin) before using any function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Consider the following composition function:

```js
import { computed, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { isInternetExplorer } from 'src/services/utils/utilsService'
import { Screen } from 'quasar'
import { auth, getAllScopes } from 'src/services/auth/authService'

const isLoginPopup = Screen.lt.sm || isInternetExplorer ? false : true
const accountID = ref('')

export const setAccountID = () => {
  const account = auth.getAccount()

  if (account) { accountID.value = account.idTokenClaims.oid } 
  else { accountID.value = '' }
}

export const useAccount = () => {
  const loading = ref(false)
  const disabled = ref(false)

  const login = async () => {
    loading.value = true
    disabled.value = true

    const allScopes = getAllScopes()

    if (isLoginPopup) {
      try {
        await auth.loginPopup(allScopes)
      } finally {
        setAccountID()
        disabled.value = false
        loading.value = false
      }
    } else {
      auth.loginRedirect(allScopes)
    }
  }

  const logout = () => { auth.logout() }

  return {
    accountID: computed(() => accountID.value),
    isAuthenticated: computed(() => Boolean(accountID.value)),
    loading: computed(() => loading.value),
    disabled: computed(() => disabled.value),
    login, logout,
  }
}
```

Now when I want to use the `isAuthenticated` computed property within `/router/index.js` Vue throws the error "***Uncaught Error: [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(plugin) before using any function***.":

```js
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

import { useAccount } from 'src/comp-functions/useAccount'

export default route(function ({ Vue }) {
  Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,

    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
  })

  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAccount()

    if (isAuthenticated || to.path === '/' || to.path === '/login') {
      next()
    } else {
      next('/login')
    }
  })

  return Router
})
```

The component API is instantiated by a [Quasar Framework boot file](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files) in the file '/boot/auth.js':

```js
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'

export default boot(({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
})
```

Is there a way to use an exported computed property outside of a component?

According to [this example](https://github.com/posva/pinia#readme), which is a library using the same composition API, it should work when `isAuthenticated` is instantiated within the `Router` object. There are [more people](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/181) struggling with this but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This problem was fixed by a friend on the Vue.js forum. For anyone else who is running into this issue I'll post his answer here. In short you need to create a separate file that will install the composition API plugin and call that file within the `router/index.ts` file to instantiate the plugin.

It’s because of the composition API not being inside Vue itself. With the release of Vue 3 this will be fixed.

You need to `Vue.use(CompositionApi)` before trying to use anything that belongs to `@vue/composition-api`.

In your `main.js` or `index.js`, the app entry point, install it first:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

This works. But I assume your file doesn’t look like this and it looks more like the next one:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'
import { isAuthenticated } from '@/store/auth'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

This will blow up everything again because the line that installs the composition API (`Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)`) is after a line that imports something that uses it (`import { unauthenticated } from '@/store/auth'`)

In the meantime, until Vue 3.0 reaches its release, you can create a file that simply installs the plugin:

```js
// installCompositionApi.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

And then in your entry point:

```js
// main.js
import './installCompositionApi.js'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { isAuthenticated } from '@/store/auth'

if (isAuthenticated.value) {
// ...
} else {
// ...
}
```

This will work.

Comment: I have the exact same error. I see you also use quasar. With quasar you have the boot files. When I follow your instructions and put the install script on top of my boot file I do not get the same result.

Comment: Have a look at my repository. Check the [boot file](https://github.com/DarkLite1/hip/blob/master/src/boot/VueCompositionApi.ts) and the [boot section in quasar.conf.je](https://github.com/DarkLite1/hip/blob/master/quasar.conf.js).

Answer (score 1):

Did you install `VueCompositionApito` correctly?

```
You must install @vue/composition-api via Vue.use() before using other APIs:
```

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api';

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi);
```

Comment: Yes it's installed correctly, and it works in all components except for outside a component. Updated OP with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error , I Just upgrade the version of @vue/composition-api .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).