# How to call a composition function from another composition in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I've been experimenting with the new composition-api in VueJS and am not sure how to solve a problem. I'm looking for some advice on how to properly implement a solution. This wasn't a problem when everything was vuex-based since you can dispatch an action to another module without a problem. However, I'm struggling to find a solution for the composition implementation.

Problem:

1. **Component** calls a **CompositionA**'s function.
2. **CompositionA** triggers a login function.
3. On **CompositionA**'s login success/failure response I would like to call a **CompositionB** function. (CompositionB contains data and logic for showing a snackbar that's used across the site)

The problem is that it is necessary to inject the snackbar dependency in every component rather than have it be instantiated/mounted from **CompositionA**. Current solution is to this effect:

```
Component.vue:

// template calls login(credentials) method
import { useCompositionA } from '@/compositions/compositionA'
import { useCompositionB } from '@/compositions/compositionB'
export default {
  name: 'Component',
  setup(props, context) {
    const { login } = useCompositionA(props, context, useCompositionB(props, context))
    return {
      login
    }
  },
}

compositionA.js:

export const useAuth = (props, context, snack) => {
  const login = async (credentials) => {
    try {
      return await loginWithEmailPassword(credentials)
      snack.show({text: 'Welcome back!'})
    } catch (err) {
      snack.show({text: 'Failed to login'})
    }
  }
  return { login }
}


compositionB.js:

export const useSnack = (props, context) => {
  const snack = reactive({
    color: 'success',
    text: null,
    timeout: 6000,
    visible: true,
  })

  const snackRefs = toRefs(snack)

  const show = ({ text, timeout, color }) => {
    snackRefs.text.value = text
    snackRefs.timeout.value = timeout || 6000
    snackRefs.color.value = color || 'success'
    snackRefs.visible.value = true
  }
  return { 
    ...snackRefs,
    show
  }
}
```

Would be nice if something like below existed, but I'm finding that the properties aren't reactive in **CompositionB** if it's used from **CompositionA** (method gets called but snackbar doesn't show up). My understanding is that Vue isn't injecting **CompositionB** into the **Component**, so I'm just running another instance of *CompositionB* inside **CompositionA**. What am I doing something wrong? What's the proper solution here?

```
compositionA.js (not working):

import { useCompositionB } from '@/compositions/compositionB'
export const useAuth = (props, context) => {
  const login = async (credentials) => {
    const { show } = useCompositionB()
    try {
      return await loginWithEmailPassword(credentials)
      show({text: 'Welcome back!'})
    } catch (err) {
      show({text: 'Failed to login'})
    }
  }
  return { login }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The idea of compositions is to abstract functionality common to multiple components (as opposed to using mixins, for example). A snackbar doesn't really seem like a good candidate for a this, as you're not going to want multiple components controlling the rendering of the snackbar. I would still be using Vuex to manage this state.

Answer (score 2):

As expected it was due to the **Component** referencing its own local copy of **CompositionB***. Solution is actually to bring the state of your compositions into the global scope according to:

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/state-management-with-composition-api/

Something like this:

```
compositionB.js:

const snack = reactive({
  color: 'success',
  text: null,
  timeout: 6000,
  visible: true,
})
export const useSnack = (props, context) => {

  const snackRefs = toRefs(snack)

  const show = ({ text, timeout, color }) => {
    snackRefs.text.value = text
    snackRefs.timeout.value = timeout || 6000
    snackRefs.color.value = color || 'success'
    snackRefs.visible.value = true
  }
  return { 
    ...snackRefs,
    show
  }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Only caveat I found initially was a composition-api error:

```
Uncaught Error: [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(plugin) before using any function.
```

This was easily solved by mounting the composition-api first thing in main.js as per solution here:

[Uncaught Error: [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(plugin) before using any function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885716/uncaught-error-vue-composition-api-must-call-vue-useplugin-before-using-any/61907559#61907559)

I think this won't be a problem with vue3 comes out. Hope this helps someone.