# Adding item object to a Array from a vue composition API

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I am trying to add the items passed from the props to a `ref` property using a `vue-composition API`. But, I don't know why the items are not added to the array. Maybe I am using the spread operator in a wrong way or my implementation is wrong but the item is not added.

`vue-composition` method is in a different file and it is used across the component.

I am passing the props to a product component in this way:

```
 <product
    :id="12345667"
    title="Pampers 9x Sensitive Baby Wet Wipes Filler, 576 Diaper Wipes"
    price="14.59"
    :rating="4"
    image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Yo4bc2uiL._AC_US160_.jpg"
  >
  </product>
```

Similarly, the product component is `setup` as:

```
   <template>

    <div class="product">
          <button type="button" @click="addToCart(item)">Add to Basket</button>
    </div>

   </template>

   <script>
    import { useCart } from "../js/ShoppingCart";
    
    export default {
      setup(props) {
        let item = props;
    
        const { addToCart } = useCart();
    
        return { item, addToCart };
      },
      props: {
        id: Number,
        title: String,
        image: String,
        price: String,
        rating: Number,
      }
    };
    </script>
```

`ShoppingCart.js` where I am using the `@vue-composition-api`

```
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
export function useCart() {
  let basket = ref([]);
  const addToCart = async (item) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    debugger;
    return {
      ...basket,
      item,
    };
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(basket));
  return { basket, addToCart };
}
```

I don't know where do I did wrong, the `basket` array is always empty while calling from different components.

Updated Question:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img
      class="home__image"
      src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AmazonExports/Fuji/2020/May/Hero/Fuji_TallHero_45M_es_US_2x._CB432534552_.jpg"
    />

    <div class="home__row">
      <product
        :id="12345667"
        title="Pampers 9x Sensitive Baby Wet Wipes Filler, 576 Diaper Wipes"
        price="14.59"
        :rating="4"
        image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Yo4bc2uiL._AC_US160_.jpg"
      >
      </product>
      <product
        :id="12345667"
        title="Pampers 9x Sensitive Baby Wet Wipes Filler, 576 Diaper Wipes"
        price="14.59"
        :rating="4"
        image="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Yo4bc2uiL._AC_US160_.jpg"
      >
      </product>
      {{ basket }}
      basket length {{ basket.value ? basket.value.length : 0 }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Product from "@/components/Product.vue";
import { useCart } from "../js/ShoppingCart";
export default {
  setup() {
    const { basket } = useCart();
    return { basket };
  },

  name: "Home",
  components: {
    Product,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any place in there where you're actually updating the `basket` array.

Also, you're not capturing the returned value, so you can remove it, and you may not need `async` function

You should be able to use `basket.value.push(item);`

*ShoppingCart.js*

```js
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
export function useCart() {
  let basket = ref([]);
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    basket.value.push(item);
  };
  return { basket, addToCart };
}
```

or `basket.push(item);` if you switch `ref` for `reactive`

*ShoppingCart.js*

```js
import { reactive } from "@vue/composition-api";
export function useCart() {
  let basket = reactive([]);
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    basket.push(item);
  };
  return { basket, addToCart };
}
```

---

### Update #1:

in your template you're using `{{ basket.value ? basket.value.length : 0 }}`

One problem is that `value` is resolved through the template, so you should not use it in the template.

---

### Update #2:

Looks like you're trying to use `useCart` as a global store. The reason that it's not working is that you are creating a new store every time you instantiate `useCart`

if you run it like this, it will create a new instance:

```js
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
export function useCart() {
  let basket = ref([]); // <--- new store, local to function
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    basket.value.push(item);
  };
  return { basket, addToCart };
}
```

but if you update it to this

```js
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
let basket = ref([]); // <--- same store, global
export function useCart() {
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    basket.value.push(item);
  };
  return { basket, addToCart };
}
```

### `useCart()` will now reuse the same ref

### Update #3:

Haven't tested, but you could try this as-well to get around the error in Vue2

```js
import { ref, isRef } from "@vue/composition-api";
let basket;
export function useCart() {
  if (! isRef(basket)) basket = ref([]);
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    basket.value.push(item);
  };
  return { basket, addToCart };
}
```

Comment: isn't `return { ...basket, item, };` pushing and returning the `basket` array?

Comment: it just returns an object with basket flattened, followed by the item

Comment: you could probably remove it (unless you need the updated values immediately, but that doesn't look like the case based on your component template)

Comment: i am using `basket length {{ basket.value ? basket.value.length : 0 }}` to display the length of the array. but the count is always 0. What could be wrong?

Comment: in the template you don't need `value`. ` {{ basket.value ? basket.value.length : 0 }}` will always return `0`, because `basket.value` is undefined(falsy)

Comment: i am not using props in the component where I am trying to render the `basket`. the updated answer is already I am using. I want to get the items from the `basket` where the item are pushed.

Comment: got the error `[vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) before using any function.`

Comment: this issue is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885716/uncaught-error-vue-composition-api-must-call-vue-useplugin-before-using-any

Comment: okay! the solution mention on that link helped. it's very dangerous to use this vue-composition unless Vue3 is fully released. else it will take the infinite time to solve the problem.