# Vue Composition API from outside of Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So, I've started using the Vue Composition API, and it's brilliant. I'm using it in a project that has Vue components, but also Vanilla JS. I'm building a notification system in Vue, as we are slowly moving everything that way.

I have the following code currently for adding a notification

```
export const useNotification = () => {
    const notifications              = ref([]);
    const visibleNotifications = computed(() => {
        return notifications.value.filter(notification => notification.visible === true).reverse();
    });

    const add = (notification: Notification) => {
        notifications.value.push(notification);
    };
};
```

I can get this adding perfectly from within Vue, but I want to also add a notification from the vanilla JS parts of the system. I've tried using `useNotification().add()` but I get the following error `[vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(plugin) before using any function.` Basically, it wants me to use it inside Vue.

Any ideas on how I get this working?

Comment: I believe this is a shortcoming of using using `vue-composition-api` with `vue2`. If you were to use `vue3`, it should be fine.

Comment: Hmm... Can't quite upgrade to Vue3 at the moment unfortunately!

Comment: Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885716/uncaught-error-vue-composition-api-must-call-vue-useplugin-before-using-any) SO question, whilst still using Vue2, it seems if I import vue into my notifications TS file, then that fixes. Gave a go, and it did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the shortcomings of using the `vue-composition-api` with `vue2`, and following the SO question [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885716/uncaught-error-vue-composition-api-must-call-vue-useplugin-before-using-any) I needed to add the following to type of my exported TS file

```
import Vue               from 'vue';
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api';

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi);
```