# Is it possible to use Vue 2 libraries in Vue 3 and vice versa?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I know, that Vue 3 has [breaking changes](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html).

But if the library doesn't use the backward incompatible features, can I use it in Vue 2 and Vue 3 simultaneously? Or I should await the release build specially build for Vue 3?

Comment: Unless you want to manually check if each library uses none of the incompatible features, you might want to wait for a Vue3 build.

Comment: @Seblor, I asked about theoretical possibility to use libraries build for Vue 2 in Vue 3. Maybe something changed in the build process and libraries built for the previous version can't be used in the next version at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Vue2 components be used in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663608/can-vue2-components-be-used-in-vue3)

Answer (score 4):

It is likely not a good idea (in production).  A number of parts of the api have been changed for example the syntax for directives has been changed, destroyed is now unmounted, scopedSlots have been merged in slots, using an empty vue object as an eventBus has been removed and many other small changes.  These can probably all be fixed quickly but until the library maintainers do so you will have issues and warnings from vue2 packages.