# vue2 and composition api - cannot import store, error [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) before using any function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, state, store, vue-composition-api

I am using vue 2.6.14 and [composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) 1.3.3 package to use composition api. I have

my main.js like

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) 
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router' 
Vue.config.productionTip = false 
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I try to setup a store

I have a `src folder / store folder / index.js`

and inside the `index.js`

```js
import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api'  

const state = reactive({
    counter : 0
})

export default{ state }
```

inside `App.vue` I try to import store to use it

```html
<script>  
import store from '@/store'  
</script>
```

I get the error `Uncaught Error: [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) before using any function.`

I tried all solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885716/uncaught-error-vue-composition-api-must-call-vue-useplugin-before-using-any) and nothing works. If I remove the `import store from '@/store'` the error goes away. Using vue 3 s not an option.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`import`s are automatically hoisted to the top of the file, so it actually precedes the `Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)` at runtime.

So these lines:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) 
import App from './App.vue'  hoisted
```

...become:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
import App from './App.vue' 
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)
```

So the plugin doesn't get installed before `App.vue` gets imported, leading to the error you observed.

### Option 1: Move plugin installation to own file

You can move the installation of `@vue/composition-api` into its own file that could be imported *before* `App.vue`:

```js
// lib/composition-api.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) 

// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import './lib/composition-api'
import App from 'App.vue'
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-importing-vue-composition-api?file=src/App.vue)

### Option 2: Use `require()` in `App.vue`

`require` the store in the component's `setup()`, where the `@vue/composition-api` would've already been installed:

```js
// App.vue
import { defineComponent, computed } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = require('@/store').default

    return {
      counter: computed(() => store.state.counter),
      increment: () => store.state.counter++,
    }
  },
})
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vue-cli-importing-vue-composition-api?file=src/App.vue)

### Option 3: Use `import()` in `App.vue`

Dynamically import the store with `import()`. *This is especially needed in Vite, which does not have `require()`.*

```js
// App.vue
import { defineComponent, computed, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = ref()
    import('@/store').then(mod => store.value = mod.default)

    return {
      counter: computed(() => store.value?.state.counter),
      increment: () => store.value && store.value.state.counter++,
    }
  },
})
```

[demo 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-importing-vue-composition-api-afhwkl?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Ok, thanks. About how mainjs and Appjs are now, I still get `Object(...) is not a function
    at setup (App.vue?234e:19)` that I cannot even explain...Any help?

Comment: My suggestion works in my local sandbox. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the new problem?

Comment: See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-importing-vue-composition-api?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: @codebot The error usually means that you messed up imports/exports. Something that you or a framework expected to be an object is actually a function. You can track down the error by clicking the link.